# Multiple tsconfig.json in vs-code for typescript project

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

First of all, I know there are several similar questions, but couldn't find solution for this problem in any of them...

So, I have an ElectronJS project created with [Nextron](https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nextron) where the file structure is something like this:

```
├── main/
│   └──...
├── renderer/
│   ├── src/
│   │   └── index.ts
│   ├── td/
│   │   └── env.d.ts
│   ├── ...
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.json
└──...
```

The content of the `tsconfig.json` file in the root is the following

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "include": ["renderer/next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "renderer/next.config.js", "app", "dist"]
}
```

while the one in `renderer/tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@src": ["src"],
      "@src/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["./td/*.ts"]
}
```

Everything works fine when I run the project via

```
npm run dev
```

or

```
npm run build
```

but in vs-code I'm getting errors (in files inside the `renderer` folder) about constants and other declarations not found (which are defined in `/renderer/td/env.d.ts`)

Which means, I could keep working just seeing errors in the IDE and then the build process would work fine (i.e. I actually can get the values of the declared environment constants and access the defined paths aliases), but it's quite annoying...

Any idea on how to make vs-code properly detect the included files?

Just in case, the content of `/renderer/ts/env/d/ts` is something like:

```js
/** Env constant set to (package.json).name */
declare const PACKAGE_NAME: string;
/** Env constant set to (package.json).version */
declare const PACKAGE_VERSION: string;
/** Env constant set to the build ID */
declare const BUILD_ID: string;
/** Env constant set to the git commit hash */
declare const COMMIT_HASH: string;
/** Env constant set to the 7 first characters of the git commit hash */
declare const COMMIT_HASH_SHORT: string;
/** Env constant set to `true` for the code to use in server side, `false` for the one delivered to the client */
declare const IS_SERVER: boolean;
/** Env constant set to `true` for the production build, `false` for development */
declare const IS_PRODUCTION: boolean;
```

which basically declares the environment variables defined in build time by webpack on NextJS

**Edit:** Uploaded a repository with the minimum configuration to reproduce this issue:
https://github.com/danikaze/vscode-multi-tsconfig

Answer (score 4):

I recently encountered a similar problem with my company's Vue JS project.
Our project repository is structured as a mono-repo so there was a root level `tsconfig.json` as well as the children app level `tsconfig.json`.

But the VS Code extension for Vue JS files (Vetur) only took the project root level `tsconfig.json` for consideration. So my individual app level `tsconfig` were being ignored and hence I also had to suffer intellisense errors.

The workaround that worked for me is in the link at the bottom.
You have to create a [Multi-root workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces).
Add both your root level directory, and the children `renderer` directory to the multi-root workspace.
Make sure that the `renderer` directory is the first entry in your `.code-workspace` file's `folders` entry.

Your `{name of your workspace}.code-workspace` file should look something like the code below.

```json
{
  "folders": [
     {
       "name": "your subdirectory app",
       "path": "./renderer"
     },
     {
       "name": "your root directory",
       "path": "."
     },
  ]
}
```

This should make VS Code account for your subdirectory's `tsconfig` file.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/762#issuecomment-623755808)

Answer (score 3):

For me adding a multi-root directive on `.vscode/settings.json` solved this issue.

I.E.

```
{
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [
    "repo1",
    "repo2",
    "repo3",
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is even related to tsconfig...

Comment: More like depending on the extension in my case.

Comment: This was a huge lifesaver for me! I was running a monorepo with a base `tsconfig.json` and `.eslintrc.js` in the repository root. I then was extending those in each package i.e. `./packages/foo` and `./packages/bar`. Running the CLI ESLint commands linted everything but when I opened a file in one of the packages, ESLint just told me that the file wasn't in my `tsconfig.json` despite it actually being there and working from the CLI. This solved it for me.

Comment: This works with Firebase Functions.

Answer (score 1):

So... I opened an issue in github and after several investigation and opening a 2nd issue, looks like in the end the problem was different.

Basically, the source of the problem was importing external data from the included file, and that, is not supported by specs.

> Because `env.d.ts` contains an import statement, the file is considered a module (module variables are not part of the global scope and instead must be explicitly imported)

> You can workaround this by explicitly declaring `PACKAGE_NAME` in the global scope:

[The solution/official thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40485#event-3760753048)